# Radio button is over the text strip payment gate way- woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

After the last update of Stripe Woocommerce plugin  the radio button is over the text of the payment method.

It seems this is only the case if a payment method image/icon is added.

Please let me know if any solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: Radio button over text-Stripe-Woo]

Answer (score 0):

It's not the ideal solution, but adding leading spaces to the title field for the payment type works for me.

Replace:

```
"Credit Card (Stripe)"
```

with:

```
"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Credit Card (Stripe)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Updating to version 4.1.12 of the WooCommerce Stripe Gateway plug-in fixed it.